# Why mysql not using the index here?

Tags: mysql, index

I created a `test table` to try and test of course if `index` is working with a help of `EXPLAIN EXTENDED` command, here is the table:

```
id | first_id | second_id | details
```

and have 7 rows and data given are:

```
id | first_id | second_id | details
1  | 1        |           | hello
2  | 2        |           | hello2
3  | 1        |           | hello3
4  |          | 1         | hello4
5  |          | 2         | hello5
6  | 1        |           | hello6
7  |          | 1         | hello7
```

And my `index` is ``` ALTER TABLE test ADD INDEX test (``first_id``) ``` (Don't know how to add the back tick properly)

Then I tried to run this query:

```
EXPLAIN EXTENDED SELECT * FROM `test` WHERE first_id = 1
```

And got this result:

[image]

From what I understand here, [How can I tell if an index is being used to sort in MySQL?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/20038/how-can-i-tell-if-an-index-is-being-used-to-sort-in-mysql), mysql does not using the `index`.

Here is what I think the reason why mysql does not used the `index`.

1. The rows are too short
2. I made a mistake

If #1 is true, then how many rows do I need until mysql use the `index`? And if #2 is true, where I go wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The percentage varies based on a lot of factors; I say "about 20%".

For tiny tables, you would be hard pressed to see any performance difference.

*Usually* the Optimizer "does the right thing" in deciding between using the index (and bouncing between the index's BTree and the data BTree) versus simply scanning the entire table (and throwing out unwanted rows).

Bottom line:  Don't worry about it.

Answer (score 0):

From the answer here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1969022/what-is-the-minimum-number-of-rows-required-to-create-an-index, it is stated that if you are selecting a rows that is under 5% of the total rows of that table (big tables), `index` will be used (assumed that there is one). And I proved it using my `test` table:

I add an index in `details` column:

```
ALTER TABLE test ADD INDEX details (`details`)
```

And tested it using this query

```
EXPLAIN EXTENDED SELECT * FROM `test` WHERE details = 'hello'
```

And I got this:

[image]

And to clear my doubt, I changed the `hello7` to `hello` from `details` column and run the query again I got this:

[image]

This means that `index` will be used if the **total # of rows of your column's data** `ex. total number of this -> WHERE column = data` is below 50% (based on my `test` table).

Simplified

```
if query_results_count < 50% of the total results of the table = index
will be used, otherwise it will use full-table scan.
```

**Note:** I based my answer on what I tested in my `localhost` and with the help of the links I mentioned. Make sure to make a test before applying it to your production site/s.